# How can I shift my class="active" to extreme right and logo in extreme left in both images?

Tags: html, css

How can I shift my `class="active"` to the extreme right and logo in extreme left in both images? This webpage is basically focusing on the responsive navbar.

I want when my max-width: 700px; my logo and dropdown icon should be available as (image 2) but logo on the extreme left and dropdown in the extreme right.

Similarly, in image 1 class="active" to extreme right and logo in the extreme left.

I am new with HTML and CSS.

I am only allowed to use HTML and CSS, no JavaScript or Bootstrap.

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar{
    background-color: #6D6A6A;
    display: flex;
}

.navbar a{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 14px 28px;
}

.navbar a:hover{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

.content p{
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#toggle{
    display: none;
}

.togglearea{
    background-color: #6D6A6A;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.togglearea label{
    background-color: white;
    height: 45px;
    width: 50px;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.togglearea label span{
    background-color: black;
    height: 4px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 2px 0px;
}

.togglearea{
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
    .navbar{
        flex-direction: column;
        display: none;
    }
#toggle:checked + .navbar{
        display: flex;
    }
.togglearea{
        display: flex;
    }
    .navbar .logo{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Responsive Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="togglearea">
        <img class="togglelogo" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/7e9/ladybird-1367182.jpg" alt="cdac logo" height="150px" width="250px">
        <label for="toggle">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </label>
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="check">

    <div class="navbar">
        <img class="logo" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/7e9/ladybird-1367182.jpg" alt="cdac logo" height="150px" width="250px">
        <a class="active" href="#">About Us</a>
        <a class="active" href="#">Logout</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur sunt corporis, ex alias nobis dicta laborum aperiam deserunt dolore doloremque? Vero reprehenderit, distinctio necessitatibus eius deleniti saepe accusantium nesciunt. Ipsum, amet, earum sit veritatis saepe veniam non fuga illo nobis quos voluptatibus nesciunt eveniet eius eum a ducimus sapiente rem quidem perspiciatis facilis odit eos architecto dolorem quis porro. Voluptas a perferendis quod facilis excepturi, dolore ab, perspiciatis vel, quidem ad tenetur aspernatur pariatur minima deserunt consequatur sit culpa quos earum ipsum possimus eum vero! Quae, iusto, rerum? Maxime inventore porro facere distinctio totam, a quis ipsum doloremque pariatur quibusdam sint, magnam quo, odio non dolorem temporibus in veniam expedita. Nisi nobis labore illo rem maiores a dicta dolor magni ducimus, nulla et quas iure in rerum quam aut culpa quod, accusantium qui ipsum, numquam saepe. Et sit modi maiores, eligendi. Architecto mollitia praesentium, quaerat omnis nulla voluptates dignissimos sapiente natus quos incidunt saepe eligendi, sunt suscipit minus quasi culpa asperiores perspiciatis quis possimus, voluptatem quisquam cum. Minima ipsa obcaecati odit debitis laudantium ut possimus, quam accusantium eum reiciendis! Numquam, repellendus, accusantium. Ab corporis, esse quidem nobis alias omnis accusantium laborum ducimus mollitia vitae provident quia magni velit, quos aliquam?
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a homework assignment. What have you tried to accomplish this? You should tell us what you tried, so we can help you. Also, saying the question is urgent is likely to get this down voted and closed.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your explication, I fixed your troubles.

I set your `a.active` into a container that I called in class `.containerActive`.

Then I set this class as follow:

```
.containerActive{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left:auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
   .containerActive{
      flex-direction: column;
      margin-left:0;
   }
}
```

So this is for the links

For the img, I only added:

```
.togglelogo{
    margin-right:auto;
  }
```

To keep it on the right under 700px width screen

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar{
    background-color: #6D6A6A;
    display: flex;
}

.navbar a{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 14px 28px;
}

.navbar a:hover{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

.content p{
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#toggle{
    display: none;
}

.togglearea{
    background-color: #6D6A6A;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.togglearea label{
    background-color: white;
    height: 45px;
    width: 50px;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.togglearea label span{
    background-color: black;
    height: 4px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 2px 0px;
}

.togglearea{
    display: none;
}

.containerActive{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left:auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px)
{
   .navbar{
        flex-direction: column;
        display: none;
    }
  #toggle:checked + .navbar{
        display: flex;
    }
  .togglearea{
        display: flex;
  }
  .togglelogo{
    margin-right:auto;
  }
  .navbar .logo{
      display: none;
  }
  .containerActive{
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Responsive Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="togglearea">
        <img class="togglelogo" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/7e9/ladybird-1367182.jpg" alt="cdac logo" height="150px" width="250px">
        <label for="toggle">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </label>
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="check">

    <div class="navbar">
        <img class="logo" src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/7e9/ladybird-1367182.jpg" alt="cdac logo" height="150px" width="250px">
        <div class="containerActive">
          <a class="active" href="#">About Us</a>
          <a class="active" href="#">Logout</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur sunt corporis, ex alias nobis dicta laborum aperiam deserunt dolore doloremque? Vero reprehenderit, distinctio necessitatibus eius deleniti saepe accusantium nesciunt. Ipsum, amet, earum sit veritatis saepe veniam non fuga illo nobis quos voluptatibus nesciunt eveniet eius eum a ducimus sapiente rem quidem perspiciatis facilis odit eos architecto dolorem quis porro. Voluptas a perferendis quod facilis excepturi, dolore ab, perspiciatis vel, quidem ad tenetur aspernatur pariatur minima deserunt consequatur sit culpa quos earum ipsum possimus eum vero! Quae, iusto, rerum? Maxime inventore porro facere distinctio totam, a quis ipsum doloremque pariatur quibusdam sint, magnam quo, odio non dolorem temporibus in veniam expedita. Nisi nobis labore illo rem maiores a dicta dolor magni ducimus, nulla et quas iure in rerum quam aut culpa quod, accusantium qui ipsum, numquam saepe. Et sit modi maiores, eligendi. Architecto mollitia praesentium, quaerat omnis nulla voluptates dignissimos sapiente natus quos incidunt saepe eligendi, sunt suscipit minus quasi culpa asperiores perspiciatis quis possimus, voluptatem quisquam cum. Minima ipsa obcaecati odit debitis laudantium ut possimus, quam accusantium eum reiciendis! Numquam, repellendus, accusantium. Ab corporis, esse quidem nobis alias omnis accusantium laborum ducimus mollitia vitae provident quia magni velit, quos aliquam?
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @MaxiGui. The solution is perfect as needed. :)